# ES6 export and import name functions?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have some functions and I want to keep them in an external js file. eg.

in functions.js

```
var double = function(x) {
  return x + x;
}

export { double };
```

Then in my main js file:

```
import double from './functions';

...

double(2)
```

I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: (0 , c.default) is not a function
    at bundle.min.js:44
```

When I read the line 44:

```
(0, _functions2.default)(2);
```

Any ideas why? What have I missed?

Comment: Is `export { double };` correct syntax? Should it not be `export double;`? --- Otherwise you'd need to use it like `double.double(2)`

Comment: @evolutionxbox `export double;` is incorrect syntax.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko because it requires `default`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Either default or curly brackets for named export. `export default foo` or `export { foo }` or `export { foo as bar }`. `export  foo` is just invalid syntax that wont parse.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @evolutionxbox No problem. BTW MDN has excellent cheatsheet with possible [export options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#Syntax).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're confusing default and named exports.

If you `export { double }` you must `import { double } from './functions';`

If you only have one export, it's preferable to use the default export:

```
export default double;
```

Then you can `import double from './functions':`

The reason for this is that named exports allow you to import only part of a module. For example:

```
export function add (a, b) { return a + b; }
export function subtract (a, b) { return a - b; }
```

You can then `import { add } from './math.js';` without importing `subtract`.

However, if you are only exporting one function from a module, the default export is more convenient.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
var double = function(x) {
  return x + x;
}

 export {double};
```

and

```
import {double} from './functions';
```

**Or**

export default double;

**and**

import double from "./functions.js";